# Form popup - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I using jQuery for creating form popup onclick, now i'm not sure how can i build this form, i looking for something like facebook form.
When you click image someone public you can see the image in bigger size and you can't scorll down or up, only when you exit the form, if there isn't any easy way to do it then i would be glad to have a simple code to creating popup form (not window) when i click a tag (using href) it will be working and i'll able to wirte inside (i not searching for alert, since it got buttons and i can't really design it in my way).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Umm.. I'd start learning HTML

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [jQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) with modal form. Click create new user to see the demo in action.